# How to generate Rect JS routes dynamically from API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have an react JS "routes" with static json data.I would like to know how to generate this routes data dynamically from API.Please check my below routes data and advise how to do this.

```
    import React from 'react';

const Dashboard = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Dashboard'));
const Colors = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Theme/Colors'));
const Typography = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Theme/Typography'));
const Widgets = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Widgets/Widgets'));
const Users = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Users/Users'));
const User = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Users/User'));
const login = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Pages/Login'));

// https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-config
const routes = [

  { path: '/', exact: true, name: 'Home' },
  { path: '/dashboard', name: 'Dashboard', component: Dashboard },
  { path: '/theme', exact: true, name: 'Theme', component: Colors },
  { path: '/theme/colors', name: 'Colors', component: Colors },
  { path: '/theme/typography', name: 'Typography', component: Typography },
  { path: '/widgets', name: 'Widgets', component: Widgets },
  { path: '/users/:id', exact: true, name: 'User Details', component: User },
];

export default routes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain which is your objective a little further?

I mean, if you know those are going to be the routes for your app, then you can control, i.e. in the /users/:id route, the ID passing it as prop to the User component you will be rendering when accessing that route.

Inside that component then you can do whatever you want, like probably fetching that user data from the API to show him his profile or whatever.

Hope that helps

Comment: Actually I can generate the above json data from api, but how to call component inside the json data (import statement etc)

Comment: I don't think you can do that. It can even be so unsecure for your application and also I don't imagine any example for trying to help you out

Comment: actually I have three columns in  sql table (path,name,component).I can generate json data for this column via api.but i have an issue for getting component (because it is an string when i take from json)...